# Does differentiability on $(a, b)$ implies continuity on $[a, b]$?

Tags: calculus

Provided that $f$ is defined on $[a, b]$, is it true that the differentiability of $f$ on $(a, b)$ implies that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ ?

I'm asking this question because I'm reading Salas's calculus and, as he goes trough some theorems, it's not clear on which interval (closed or open) the function is defined.

For example, in one of the proofs the following is asserted: $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$; let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be any two numbers on $(a,b)$; then f is continuous on $[ x_1$ , $x_2]$. That would seem to be true if $x_1$ is different from $a$ and $x_2$ is different from $b$. And nothing is said explicitly about which values $f$ may take on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Well, $x\in(a,b)$ means $a<x<b$ (in particular, $a\ne x\ne b$), thus neither $x_1$ equals $a$ nor $x_2$ equals $b$ when $x_1, x_2\in(a,b)$.

Comment: I see now the whole picture. Thanks for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the function differentiable on $(0,1); f(x)=x$, $f(0)=f(1)=2$ it is not continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the simple counter-example. Is it still true that true if $x_1$ is different from $a$ and $x_2$ is different from $b$, then $f$ is continuous on [$x_1$, $x_2$] ?

Comment: @muimerp if $f$ is continuous in $A$ and $B\subset A$, then $f$ is continuous in $B$. This holds because continuity is a local notion. Now, just take $A=(a,b)$ and $B=[x_1, x_2]$.

Answer (score 4):

No. Consider for instance the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1   \quad \text{for $0 < x < 1$}, \\ 0  \quad \text{for $x = 0 $ or $x = 1$}\end{cases}.$$
This function is differentiable on $(0,1)$, but the function is not continuous on the interval $[0,1]$.

About your second question: if you take $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the *open* interval $(a,b)$, then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are certainly different from $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right: it's silly to say that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different from $a$ and $b$ when it is supposed that they belong to the open interval $(a,b)$. So what exactly are they saying about the numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ ? Is their claim incorrect?

Comment: The only thing they are saying about $x_1$ and $x_2$, is that these numbers are different from the numbers $a$ and $b$. The claim is correct: if a function is differentiable on an open interval, then the function is continuous on any (closed) subinterval. The reason why the domain interval of $f$ is open is this: Intuitively, in order to define differentiability of $f$ in a point $x$, one needs to know how $f$ behaves at both sides of this point $x$.

Comment: Sorry. One final question: do you mean a proper subinterval?

Comment: Yes. If the subinterval is closed, then it is a proper subinterval (i.e. it doesn't contain $a$ or $b$).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is meant that $f(a)$ is the limiting value of the continuous $f$ on $(a,b)$ as $x$ tends to $a$. Similarly for $b$.